# Using SSL with Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-core, xunit.net, asp.net-core-1.1

Visual Studio 2017 with ASP.NET Core 1.1. Unit Testing with xUnit and Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer

The code below, copied from the official core source code, works as expected, however, if you change the Uri to http**s**://example.com, the response is 404:

```
[Fact]
public async Task CheckPermanentRedirectToHttps()
{
    var options = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent();
    var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
        .Configure(app =>
        {
            app.UseRewriter(options);
        });
    var server = new TestServer(builder);

    var response = await server.CreateClient().GetAsync(new Uri("http://example.com"));

    Assert.Equal("https://example.com/", response.Headers.Location.OriginalString);
    Assert.Equal(StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently, (int)response.StatusCode);
}
```

How can I make the https work like the http with the `TestServer`?

Comment: It is working. The only code in that application is to redirect from http to https. Once you get past that then there is nothing to handle the requests so you get a 404.

Comment: @Tratcher thank you, I got what you meant. This was my mistake.